# Automatic image format detection in PHP

Tags: php, image, format, jpeg

I am looking for a way to take a user uploaded image that is currently put in a temporary location ex: /tmp/jkhjkh78 and create a php image from it, autodetecting the format.

Is there a more clever way to do this than a bunch of try/catching with imagefromjpeg, imagefrompng, etc?

Answer (score 27):

This is one of the functions of [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). They probably should have called it "getimageinfo", but that's PHP for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
   //Image Processing
    $cover = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
    $cover_tmp_name = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
    $cover_img_path = '/images/';
    $type = exif_imagetype($cover_tmp_name);

if ($type == (IMAGETYPE_PNG || IMAGETYPE_JPEG || IMAGETYPE_GIF || IMAGETYPE_BMP)) {
        $cover_pre_name = md5($cover);  //Just to make a image name random and cool :D
/**
 * @description : possible exif_imagetype() return values in $type
 * 1 - gif image
 * 2 - jpg image
 * 3 - png image
 * 6 - bmp image
 */
        switch ($type) {    #There are more type you can choose. Take a look in php manual -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php
            case '1' :
                $cover_format = 'gif';
                break;
            case '2' :
                $cover_format = 'jpg';
                break;
            case '3' :
                $cover_format = 'png';
                break;
            case '6' :
                $cover_format = 'bmp';
                break;

            default :
                die('There is an error processing the image -> please try again with a new image');
                break;
        }
    $cover_name = $cover_pre_name . '.' . $cover_format;
      //Checks whether the uploaded file exist or not
            if (file_exists($cover_img_path . $cover_name)) {
                $extra = 1;
                while (file_exists($cover_img_path . $cover_name)) {
        $cover_name = md5($cover) . $extra . '.' . $cover_format;
                    $extra++;
                }
            }
     //Image Processing Ends
```

this will make image name look cool and unique

Answer (score 5):

Use `exif_imagetype()` if it's available ..:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

I'm pretty sure exif functions are available by default (i.e. you have to specifically exclude them rather than specifically include them) when you install php

Answer (score 2):

You could try [`finfo_file()`](http://www.php.net/finfo_file), apparently an improved version of [`mime_content_type()`](http://www.php.net/mime_content_type).

Edit: OK, `getimagesize()` is better..

Answer (score 0):

You can call a system command (if you're under linux/unix), `file` if you like:

```
kender@eira:~$ file a
a: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to know the Extension as well as result based on condition

> $image_file = 'http://foo.com/images.gif';
>   $extension = substr($image_file, -4); 
> if($extension == ".jpg"){ echo 'Its a JPG Image.'; } else { echo 'Its not a JPG Image.'; }

Comment: First of all there's no check for the extensions jpeg, jpe, jif and jfif. While uncommon, they're still used by some people (Mostly jpeg though). Moreover, the extension doesn not necessarily reflect the image format and uploading a PHP file with the JPG extension could be fatal if a website is vulnerable to local file inclusion.

Comment: @TimeSheep jif, jifif and jpe extensions can be converted to jpeg at anytime without problem, just by renaming them. jif is shorter to jifif due to old windows system that could not recognize 4 digit extensions. Soo that wont be a problem as much is .gif .svg .png .psd(simple layered psds can be viewed through browser) ...

Any nice logic WhiteHorse, keep it up :D

Comment: If I thought the format thing was significant, I'd probably have edited it in :) It's just something to note. The more significant thing I mentioned is that `end(explode($image_file, "."))` would be a smarter approach, as you can then handle extensions of arbitrary length. Finally, using try/catch is in fact marginally safer, as someone who for some reason has execute but not write access, could upload a script disguised as an image and then execute it. But that's probably a stupid edge case :) I'm not sure, but `getimagesize()` might also prevent that issue.

Answer (score 0):

People are recommending using [`getimagesize()` but the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) reads:

> **Caution** This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a
>   non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image
>   and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain
>   nonsensical values.
>
> Do not use `getimagesize()` to check that a given file is a valid image.
>   Use a purpose-built solution such as the [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension instead.

The relevant function in the Fileinfo extension is [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php):

```
string finfo_file ( resource $finfo , string $file_name = NULL 
    [, int $options = FILEINFO_NONE [, resource $context = NULL ]] )
```

> Returns a textual description of the contents of the `file_name`
>   argument, or **FALSE** if an error occurred.

Example return values given are: `text/html`, `image/gif`, `application/vnd.ms-excel`

However, comments on the official documentation page warn that this shouldn't be relied on for validation either.