# how to get original image extension

Tags: php, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic image format detection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189391/automatic-image-format-detection-in-php)

Let's say I have an image "abc.gif" and I renamed it to "abc.jpg", but both

```
echo $_FILES['imageupload']['type'];
```

and

```
echo mime_content_type($_FILES['imageupload']['type']);
```

output "image/jpg".

How could I get the original extension which is .gif not .jpg?

Comment: you mean you renamed the file *before* upload? Or *after* the upload in php? Why would you rename it to wrong extension?

Comment: You **cannot** get the "original" extension, but you probably don't care about it as well (what do you care if it was `.jpg` or `.jpeg`?). See the dupe question to learn how you can get the image *type*.

Comment: @Jon what if a user try to upload an image which has an extension jpg and he changes it into .gif???

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // Returns a magic database resource (we are gone search through mime-types)

foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n"; // Return mime-type of every file
}

finfo_close($finfo);

?>
```

Comment: And a bit of explanation of what that code actually does.