# FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified

Tags: php, fpdf

I am getting the error as mentioned on the title when I try to run my php code which will generate a PDF file. This is the current code I am using:

```
 $pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

foreach($inventories as $key => $inventories) :

    $image = $inventories['image'];
    $resourceID = $inventories['resourceID'];
    $learningcentre = $inventories['learningcentre'];
    $title = $inventories['title'];
    $quantity = $inventories['quantity'];
    $description = $inventories['description'];

    $html= 'Resource ID: '. $resourceID. '<br>Title: '.$title.'<br>Learning Centre: '.$learningcentre.'<br>Quantity: '.$quantity.'<br>Description: '.$description.'<br><br>';
    $pdf->Image('images/'.$image,10,6,30);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);             
 endforeach; 

$pdf->Output();
```

My images are currently stored in the images folder and I have converted the images file type to "File" by using these codes:

```
$fileTypes = array(
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif'
    );

    // default value for unsuccessful move file
    $successfullyMoveFile = false;

    // the name of the input type 
    $fileInputName = 'file';

    // an array to store all the possible errors related to uploading a file
    $fileErrorMessages = array();

    //if file is not empty
    $uploadFile = !empty($_FILES); 

    if ($uploadFile) 
    {
        $fileUploaded = $_FILES[$fileInputName];

        // if we have errors while uploading!!
        if ($fileUploaded['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
        {
            $errorCode = $fileUploaded['error']; // this could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7.
            $fileErrorMessages['file'] = $uploadErrors[$errorCode];
        }

        // now we check for file type
        $fileTypeUploaded = $fileUploaded['type'];

        $fileTypeNotAllowed = !in_array($fileTypeUploaded, $fileTypes);
        if ($fileTypeNotAllowed) 
        {
            $fileErrorMessages['file'] = 'You should upload a .jpg, .png or .gif file';
        }

        // if successful, we want to copy the file to our images folder
        if ($fileUploaded['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
        {

            $successfullyMoveFile = move_uploaded_file($fileUploaded["tmp_name"], $imagesDirectory . $newFileName);

        }
    }
```

I believed the problem lies with the file type. Is there any way allow FPDF to understand the file type?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions in the error message are quite clear but I'll try to explain them with another words since you're finding some difficulties. The [Image()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm) function has a `type` parameter described this way:

> Image format. Possible values are (case insensitive): JPG, JPEG, PNG
>   and GIF. If not specified, the type is inferred from the file
>   extension.

For instance, if the picture is a GIF you need to type `'GIF'` (don't forget the quotes). The following example is provided:

```
$pdf->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',60,30,90,0,'PNG');
```

But you call the function this way:

```
$pdf->Image('images/'.$image,10,6,30);
```

You've left the type empty, so FPDF (as documented) will try to guess the image type from the file extension. The extension is the trailing part of the file name after the dot. For instance, if the file is called `kitten.jpg` then the extension is `jpg` and FPDF will assume it's a JPEG picture. The following example is provided:

```
$pdf->Image('logo.png',10,10,-300);
```

Back to your code, I have no way to know what `$image` or `$newFileName` contain (you've managed to omit all the relevant code) but, given the error message, I'd say it doesn't end with a file extension that FPDF can recognise; it probably doesn't even have an extension at all. So you need to either append the file extension to the file name *or* store the file type anywhere else (e.g. a database table). You could also use heuristics to find out the image type but I don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for omitting the relevant code for $image. The problem is with my image files having no extension. However, I removed their extension so that my webpage is able to print out the image regardless of which extension they are previously in. Is there anyway for FPDF to read and print out images with no extension?

Comment: What do mean exactly? Something like an optional parameter in the `Image()` function that let's you instruct FPDF about the image type?

Comment: Erm.. I don't really know what is optional parameter. http://i.imgur.com/oICdKXc.png The link shows the file type my images is currently stored in. Basically I need to allow my PDF to print out the image. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189391/automatic-image-format-detection-in-php

Comment: why don't you save the extension of your images when you save them, then read it to pass it to the ` image` function?