# Finding out what file type something is in php

Tags: php, image, backend, server-side

What is the quickest way on the user side to make sure an uploaded file is actually an image? I am somewhat new to php (9 months experience) and I don't know all of the functions. I am trying to build a social media site, and don't know how to figure out on the back end what file it is., but it did not seem to have a clear answer. There was another question asked that was similar to this Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: you have asked for both front and back end image checking, which is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic image format detection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189391/automatic-image-format-detection-in-php)

Comment: backend, when i said user side i meant what way is quickest for the user

Comment: well the quickest way for the user is some front end validation otherwise you have to wait for the whole file to be uploaded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828554/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-accept-only-image-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php build in function: https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.mime-content-type.php

```
<?php
    echo mime_content_type('php.gif') . "\n";
    echo mime_content_type('test.php');
?>
```

Will output:

```
image/gif
text/plain
```

**Condition Example I**: JPG Images only

```
if (\mime_content_type('image.jpg' /* full path to image */) === "image/jpg") {
    // do something
}
```

**Condition Example II**: Any type of images

```
if (\strpos(\mime_content_type('image.jpg' /* full path to image */), 'image/') !== false) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Does it output that as a string, to where i can say if (mime_content_type(image.jpg) == "image/jpg") {}

Comment: Yes kind off, I added some examples